# How to get value of an attribute of html element inside variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code for get `data-isAirTour` attribute but always is undefined.

```
var tours = $('#WrapTours').find('div.tour');
  var toursTmp;
      var length = tours.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (tours.eq(i).value.data('isForeignTour') == isForeignTour) {
                        toursTmp.push(tours[i]);
                    }
                }
```

html:

```
<div class="col-sms-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 tour" data-isAirTour="@item.IsAirTour" data-isForeignTour="@item.IsForeignTour" data-TourType="@item.TourType">
    </div>
```

How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly provide the HTML code as well?

Comment: What's `i` in `tours[i]`? We need a [mcve]

Comment: use this `tours.eq(i).data('isForeignTour')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tours[i]` will return DOM element. To get jQuery object use `.eq(index)`, to get the object at index then you can use jQuery methods like `.attr()`

```
tours.eq(i).attr('data-isAirTour')
```

Comment: or `tours.eq(i).data('isAirTour');`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the other proposed solutions, you can also use the vanilla JS `getAttribute()` method, like so:

```js
var tours = $('#WrapTours').find('div.tour');
for (var i = 0; i < tours.length; i++) {
  var attr01 = tours[i].getAttribute("data-isAirTour");
  console.log(attr01);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="WrapTours">
  <div class="tour" data-isAirTour="yes"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `dataset.isairtour` (remember to keep it all in lowercase) to achieve the same result:

```js
var tours = $('#WrapTours').find('div.tour');
for (var i = 0; i < tours.length; i++) {
  var attr01 = tours[i].dataset.isairtour;
  console.log(attr01);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="WrapTours">
  <div class="tour" data-isAirTour="yes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also `tours[i].dataset.isAirTour`

Comment: ahh right, should be `tours[i].dataset.isairtour`. If the data property used hypens (`data-is-air-tour`) then `dataset.isAirTour` is the way to get it

Comment: @chazsolo I added your suggestion as another option, hope you don't mind. :)